# Python list to sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('stadiumsDB.db')
c = conn.cursor()

c.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Stadium;

CREATE TABLE Stadium (
    id     INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    Stadium   TEXT UNIQUE,
    Club   Text UNIQUE,
    Location  Text UNIQUE
)
''')
main_site = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Premier_League_stadiums').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(main_site)
column_names = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('th')[:9]]
print column_names
stadium_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
stadium_data = [[td.getText() for td in stadium_rows[i].findAll('td')]
            for i in range(len(stadium_rows))]
print stadium_data
```

I want to build a sqlite database. First row of the table will be the column name and i want them import from my column_names variable. Next rows i want them import from stadium_data variable. Any guidance please !!!!

Comment: you do know that normally you do not store column names in the table itself in sql-databases? - that wouldnt play well with queries as you would have to ecxlude the names-row explicitly in all of them

Comment: if you just want to store the data without needing sql(ite)-specific stuff then csv (you can write column names more conveniently) or json (generally very flexible) would propably be better alternatives. (both in standard library)

Comment: all i want is to put the table in that site to a sqlite database.

Answer (score 0):

For your table definition you can insert `stadium_data` best with [executemany](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) like

```
cn=column_names

stadium=cn.index("Stadium")
club=cn.index("Club")
location=cn.index("Location")
# this is for making sure that column order is correct

c.executemany("insert into stadium(stadium, club, location) values (?,?,?)",
              ((row[stadium], row[club],row[location]) for row in stadium_data))
```

This does not put `column_names` first in the table as this is doesnt seem like a good idea to me but you can do so with (insert this before the executemany)

```
c.execute("insert into stadium(id,stadium, club, location) values (?,?,?,?)",
          (0,cn[stadium], cn[club],cn[location]))
```